# What is an easy way to test whether any process of a given id is presently running on Linux?

Tags: c++, linux

In C++, I have a resource that is tied to a pid.  Sometimes the process associated with that pid exits abnormally and leaks the resource.

Therefore, I'm thinking of putting the pid in the file that records the resource as being in use.  Then when I go to get a resource, if I see an item as registered as being in use, I would search to see whether a process matching the pid is currently running, and if not, clean up the leaked resource.

I realize there is a very small probability that a new unrealated pid is now sharing the same number, but this is better than leaking with no clean up I have now.

Alternatively, perhaps there is a better solution for this, if so, please suggest, otherwise, I'll pursue the pid recording.

Further details: The resource is a port number for communication between a client and a server over tcp.  Only one instance of the client may use a given port number on a machine.  The port numbers are taken from a range of available port numbers to use.  While the client is running, it notes the port number it is using in a special file on disk and then cleans this entry up on exit.  For abnormal exit, this does not always get cleaned up and the port number is left annotated as being in use, when it is no longer being used.

Comment: What system do you want this for? It'll be different (for example) under Windows than Linux.

Comment: If you're running linux you may want to take a look at the utility pidof. If you find your own pid, you're running.

Comment: the assumption that pid would not repeat itself it fine. unless you have a case of thousands of shortlived processes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To check for existence of process with a given id, use `kill(pid,0)` (I assume you are on POSIX system). See `man 2 kill` for details.

Also, you can use `waitpid` call to be notified when the process finishes.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you use some kind of OS resource, not a PID. Mutexes, semaphores, delete-on-close files. All of these are cleaned up by the OS when a process exits.

On Windows, I would recommend a named mutex.

On Linux, I would recommend using flock on a file.

Comment: I am not aware of a way to do delete-on-close on Linux. Note that you can delete a file while still having it open, then it will be deleted when the last file handle is closed. Of course, once deleted, the only way to access it is through one of the existing handles, so this may not be useful to you.

Comment: True, but the `flock` (advisory lock on a file) will be released. That is something other processes can detect. Still, I'd probably go for Roman's suggestion of using `kill(PID, 0)`, or check the existence of `/proc/1234` for PID 1234. (But your comment confuses me a little. Did you reply to a comment that was subsequently deleted?)

Answer (score 2):

How about a master process that starts your process (the one which terminates abnormally) waits for your process to crash (waitpid) and spawns it again when waitpid returns.

```
while(1) {
fork exec
waitpid
}
```

Comment: This is the only sane way to manage processes, at least on Unix.

Answer (score 0):

*The problem domain isn't clear, unfortunately, you could try re-explaining it in some other way.*

But if I understand you correctly, you could create a map like

```
std::map< ProcessId, boost::shared_ptr<Resource> > map;
// `Resource` here references to some abstract resource type
// and `ProcessId` on Windows system would be basically a DWORD
```

and in this case you simply have to list every running process (this can be done via [EnumProcesses call](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684865(VS.85).aspx) on Windows) and remove every entry with inappropriate id from your `map`. After doing this you would have only valid process-resource pairs left. This action can be repeated every `YY` seconds depending on your needs.

Note that in this case removing an item from your map would basically call the corresponding destructor *(because, if your resource is not being used in your code somewhere else, it's reference count would drop to zero).*

Answer (score 0):

The API that achieves that on windows are [OpenProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684320%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) which takes process ID as input, and [GetExitCodeProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683189%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) which returns STILL_ACTIVE when the process is, well, still active. You could also use any Wait function with zero timeout, but this API seems somewhat cleaner.

As other answers note, however, this doesn't seem a promising road to take. We might be able to give more focused advice if you provide more scenario details. What is your platform? What is the leaked resource exactly? Do you have access to the leaking app code?  Can you wrap it in a high-level try-catch with some cleanup? If not, maybe wait on the leaker to finish with a dedicated thread (or dedicated process altogether)?  Any detail you provide might help.

Comment: More details are now added above.

Comment: So - is it indeed windows?  Is the said client part of your code?  Do the suggested alternatives make sense in your case?

Comment: Since the title indicates Linux, I doubt that references to Windows API functions are all that helpful.